# Catch with regex only the first element in a list(can be multiple, but not one after another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following text:

```
Application\n- Lorem\n -Auto 
Applications:\n- Lorem2\n -Auto
```

If there is no ':' I want to change it in:

```
Application:\n- Lorem
```

I tried but is failing:

```
 text = text.replace('\n-', ':\n-')
 text = re.sub('\n-', ':\n-', text)
```

In a textarea I want to achieve:

```
Application:
- Lorem
- Auto
```

I can replace `::` but is adding ':' after each `\n-` which catch all in list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do with a lookbehind avoiding the colon.

```
text = re.sub('(?<!:)\n-', ':\n-', text)
```